# How do I actually connect to botfront on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, rasa

I tried deploying on EKS, and my config.yaml follows this suggested format:

```
botfront:
   app:
# The complete external host of the Botfront application (eg. botfront.yoursite.com). It must be set even if running on a        private or local DNS (it populates the ROOT_URL).
       host: botfront.yoursite.com
mongodb:
   enabled: true # disable to use an external mongoDB host
# Username of the MongoDB user that will have read-write access to the Botfront database. This is not the root user
    mongodbUsername: username
# Password of the MongoDB user that will have read-write access to the Botfront database. This is not the root user
    mongodbPassword: password
# MongoDB root password
     mongodbRootPassword: rootpassword
```

And I ran this command:

```
helm install -f config.yaml -n botfront --namespace botfront botfront/botfront
```

and the deployment appeared successful with all pods listed as running.

But botfront.yoursite.com goes nowhere. I checked the ingress and it matches, but there are no external ip addresses or anything. I don't know how to actually access my botfront site once deployed on kubernetes.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

With nginx lb installed `kubectl get ingresses -n botfront` now
returns:

```
NAME                   CLASS    HOSTS                ADDRESS                                                                         PORTS   AGE
botfront-app-ingress   <none>   botfront.cream.com   a182b0b24e4fb4a0f8bd6300b440e5fa-423aebd224ce20ac.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com   80      4d1h
```

and

`kubectl get svc -n botfront` returns:

```
NAME                        TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
botfront-api-service        NodePort   10.100.207.27   <none>        80:31723/TCP      4d1h
botfront-app-service        NodePort   10.100.26.173   <none>        80:30873/TCP      4d1h
botfront-duckling-service   NodePort   10.100.75.248   <none>        80:31989/TCP      4d1h
botfront-mongodb-service    NodePort   10.100.155.11   <none>        27017:30358/TCP   4d1h
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run `kubectl get svc -n botfront`, it will show you all the `Services` that expose your `botfront`

```
$ kubectl get svc -n botfront
NAME                        TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
botfront-api-service        NodePort   10.3.252.32    <none>        80:32077/TCP      63s
botfront-app-service        NodePort   10.3.249.247   <none>        80:31201/TCP      63s
botfront-duckling-service   NodePort   10.3.248.75    <none>        80:31209/TCP      63s
botfront-mongodb-service    NodePort   10.3.252.26    <none>        27017:31939/TCP   64s
```

Each of them is of type [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport), which means it exposes your app on the external IP address of each of your **EKS** cluster nodes on a specific port.

So if you your **node1** ip happens to be `1.2.3.4` you can acess `botfront-api-service` on `1.2.3.4:32077`. Don't forget to allow access to this port on **firewall/security groups**. If you have any registered domain e.g. `yoursite.com` you can configure for it a subdomain `botfront.yoursite.com` and point it to one of your **EKS** nodes. Then you'll be able to access it using your domain. This is the simplest way.

To be able to access it in a more effective way than by using specific node's IP and non-standard port, you may want to expose it via [`Ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) which will create an external load balancer, making your `NodePort` services available under one external IP adress and standard http port.

**Update:** I see that this chart already comes with `ingress` that exposes your app:

```
$ kubectl get ingresses -n botfront 
NAME                   HOSTS                   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
botfront-app-ingress   botfront.yoursite.com             80      70m
```

If you retrieve its yaml definition by:

```
$ kubectl get ingresses -n botfront -o yaml
```

you'll see that it uses the following annotation:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

which means you need [nginx-ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx) installed on your **EKS** cluster. This might be one reason why it fails. As you can see in my example, this ingress doesn't get any external IP. That's because **nginx-ingress** wasn't installed on my **GKE** cluster. Not sure about **EKS** but as far as I know it doesn't come with **nginx-ingress** preinstalled.

One more thing: I assume that in your `config.yaml` you put some real domain name that you have registered instead of `botfront.yoursite.com`. Suppose your domain is `yoursite.com` and you successfully created subdomain `botfront.yoursite.com`, you should redirected it to the IP of your load balancer (the one used by your `ingress`).

If you run `kubectl get ingresses -n botfront` but the `ADDRESS` is empty, you probably don't have **nginx-ingress** installed and the underlying load balancer cannot be created. If you have here some external IP address, then redirect your registered domain to this address.

Comment: I installed the ingress nginx with ```kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.43.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml
``` but I still can't access botfront.yoursite.com

Comment: This command: ```kubectl get ingresses -n botfront```

Shows the ingress:
```botfront-app-ingress   <none>   botfront.cream.com   a182b0b24e4fb4a0f8bd6300b440e5fa-423aebd224ce20ac.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com   80      24m```

but the ingress goes to a 404

Comment: Are you accessing it via domain `botfront.cream.com` ? I don't see any `A` record configured for it. What about ingress IP ? As far as I can see `kubectl get ingresses -n botfront` doesn't show any external IP. Does it still look like this ? What about `kubectl get svc -n botfront`. Please add those outputs by editing your question. It will be better visible than when you post them in comments.

Comment: sorry about that. Edited my original post.

Comment: I've tried botfront.cream.com, and I've tried a182b0b24e4fb4a0f8bd6300b440e5fa-423aebd224ce20ac.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. Both with ports at the end and without.

Comment: Thanks for posting all the updates but you didn't say anything about your domain configuration. If your domain happens to be `botfront.cream.com`, it is not configured properly. If you run e.g. `dig any botfront.cream.com` it doesn't return either `A` or `CNAME` record. You can compare it with the result of digging `cream.com`. If instead the IP address you only see domain `a182b0b24e4fb4a0f8bd6300b440e5fa-423aebd224ce20ac.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`, you should simply configure your `botfront.cream.com` subdomain so that it points with `CNAME` record to the above mentioned aws domain.